# Get HTMLElement with Prototype selector

Tags: javascript, dom, prototypejs

Prototype selectors `$`, `$$`...etc return extended object `Element`. But some times I need simple, not extended, `HTMLElement` object. How can I get it using Prototype selectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Prototype.js modifies `Element`'s prototype, whose methods are inherit by `HTMLElement`.

`$` is equivalent to `document.getElementById`, and returns a plain element, or `null`.
`$$` is similar to `document.querySelectorAll`, but returns an `Array` instead of a `NodeList`.

The easy way to proof it, run the following code on a page where Prototype.js is used:

```
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Element));
```

Instead of just `prototype`, this prints a whole list, similar to:

```
cache,Methods,_attributeTranslations,_returnOffset,_getContentFromAnonymousElement,_insertionTranslations,visible,toggle,hide,show,remove,update,replace,insert,wrap,inspect,recursivelyCollect,ancestors,descendants,firstDescendant,immediateDescendants,previousSiblings,nextSiblings,siblings,match,up,down,previous,next,getElementsBySelector,getElementsByClassName,readAttribute,writeAttribute,getHeight,getWidth,classNames,hasClassName,addClassName,removeClassName,toggleClassName,observe,stopObserving,cleanWhitespace,empty,descendantOf,scrollTo,getStyle,getOpacity,setStyle,setOpacity,getDimensions,makePositioned,undoPositioned,makeClipping,undoClipping,cumulativeOffset,positionedOffset,absolutize,relativize,cumulativeScrollOffset,getOffsetParent,viewportOffset,clonePosition,childElements,Simulated,extend,hasAttribute,addMethods,ClassNames,childOf,prototype,length,name,arguments,caller
```